# firebase not displaying text from editText

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't seem to find an answer to the issue with firebase database text. I am trying to build a review app. sending review data to database is not an issue, however edit text fields are displayed as .AppCompatEditText, pls, refer to the picture uploaded.

[image]

this return NULL in the fields of the review.

my review view holder snippet is:

```
public void bindToReview(Review review, View.OnClickListener starClickListener) {
   author.setText(String.valueOf(review.author);
   categories.setText(review.categories);
   buss_name.setText(String.valueOf(review.businessName).trim());
   buss_address.setText(String.valueOf(review.addressData).trim());
   location.setText(review.location);
   district.setText(review.district);
   reviewData.setText(String.valueOf(review.reviewData).trim());
   date.setText(review.date);
   likeCount.setText(String.valueOf(review.likeCount));
   starsData.setRating(stars);

    likes.setOnClickListener(starClickListener);
}
```

sending data to firebase:

```
 public Review(String uid, String author, String categories, String location, String district,
              String businessName, String reviewData, String addressData, float rating,
              String priceS, String sd) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.author = author;
    this.categories = categories;
    this.location = location;
    this.district = district;
    this.reviewData = reviewData;
    this.businessName = businessName;
    this.addressData = addressData;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.sd = sd;
    this.priceS = priceS;
}

@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("uid", uid);
    result.put("author", author);
    result.put("categories", categories);
    result.put("location", location);
    result.put("name", businessName);
    result.put("address", addressData);
    result.put("district", district);
    result.put("date", sd);
    result.put("body", reviewData);
    result.put("stars", rating);
    result.put("price", priceS);
    result.put("likeCount", likeCount);
    result.put("likes", likes);
    return result;
}
```

adapter:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReviewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.uid.setText(String.valueOf(reviewsList.get(position).uid));
    holder.categories.setText(reviewsList.get(position).categories);
    holder.author.setText(reviewsList.get(position).author);
    holder.businessName.setText(String.valueOf(reviewsList.get(position).businessName));
    holder.address.setText(String.valueOf(reviewsList.get(position).addressData));
    holder.reviewData.setText(String.valueOf(reviewsList.get(position).reviewData));
    holder.likes.setText(String.valueOf(reviewsList.get(position).likeCount));
    holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(reviewsList.get(position).priceS));
    holder.date.setText(reviewsList.get(position).sd);
    holder.stars.setText(String.valueOf(reviewsList.get(position).rating));

    final RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder);
    Glide.with(mContext).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
            .load(reviewsList.get(position).review_image).into(holder.reviewImage);
}
```

what could be the issue? thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you show us how you set that data in the database?

Comment: i have a picture there, pls, take a look.

Comment: I've seen that. I was asking hoe you set it programmatically.

Comment: Please provide part of the code when you send your data to Firebase.

Comment: added the code snippets... still getting null in my textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by simple editText.getText().toString(); not String.valueOf(editText). don't know why one works, and other doesn't.